# Why can you inherit a class over project boundaries, but not its attached XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inheritance, user-controls

(this question is a refinement of [my other question on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493572/why-do-i-get-a-xamlparseexception-when-i-inherit-a-custom-usercontrol-in-another) which was a bit complicated but I really want to understand why this doesn't work so **here's a more straight-forward example**)

**WHAT I WANT TO DO: create a simple class (no XAML) in one project which inherits a WPF UserControl (with XAML) in another project.**

Here is my inheriting class in my main project:

**EmployeeEditor.cs:**

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using CoreApp;

namespace TestInheritUserControl234
{
    class EmployeeEditor : BaseEditor
    {
        public EmployeeEditor()
        {
            TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
            tb.Text = "This was added in EmployeeEditor";
            tb.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
            EditorContent.Children.Add(tb);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my base class in my second project, notice it has **x:Name="EditorContent"**:

**BaseEditor.xaml:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="CoreApp.BaseEditor"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <StackPanel x:Name="EditorContent" Margin="5">
        <TextBlock x:Name="TheMessage" Text="This was added in BaseEditor XAML."/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

**BaseEditor.xaml.cs:**

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
namespace CoreApp
{
    public partial class BaseEditor : UserControl
    {
        public BaseEditor()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
            tb.Text = "This was added in BaseEditor code-behind.";
            EditorContent.Children.Add(tb);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when this is run, I get the error **The name 'EditorContent' does not exist in the current context**.

However, if all classes are in **one project**, it runs fine.

**Why would it be that you can inherit a class over project boundaries, but not its  attached XAML?**

Answer (score 1):

Default protection level is internal if I'm not mistaken, that's the problem in this case. To fix it change StackPanel declaration as follows:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="EditorContent" x:FieldModifier="public" Margin="5">
```

UPDATE: This brings up another problem indeed, which seems to be a limitation of WPF: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/4f6385ea-a176-489e-9f13-0c812195e323 Microsoft specifically prevents inheriting XAML-defined classes from another assembly for some reason. Quote from System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent():

```
if ((info2 == null) || (info2.Assembly != component.GetType().Assembly))
{
    throw new Exception(SR.Get("UriNotMatchWithRootType", new object[] { component.GetType(), resourceLocator }));
}
```

Comment: If I do that, it tells me: "The component "TestInheritUserControl234.CustomerEditor" does not have a resource which can be identified by "/CoreApp;component/baseeditor.xaml". (ORIGINAL: "Die Komponente "TestInheritUserControl234.CustomerEditor" verfügt nicht über eine Ressource, die vom URI "/CoreApp;component/baseeditor.xaml" identifiziert wird.")

Comment: Ah, this must be why the new WPF CrystalReportsViewer cannot be inherited from.